# How to change App root / Project path when hosting React app with AWS Amplify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I hosted my react app with AWS Amplify but nothing shows up when I open the url and everything was deployed successfully. I believe this is because AWS is not using the correct path to my project. My general project folder structure is:

- App folder:

  - Backend folder
  - Client folder

My react app is the client folder and I think Amplify is not picking up on that. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your client folder is built for react the command is npm run build.

If you need to change root paths, go to node_modules/webpack/webpack.config.js

This file holds all information on how your app is rendered

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the amplify app and restarted the process and noticed I had to specify it was a monorepo and added the app root = client folder in the yaml and it works as expected.